# nodemon + browserSync gulp task causes EADDRINUSE :::3000 error

Tags: node.js, express, browser-sync, nodemon, gulp-task

I am having issues creating a nodemon + browserSync via gulp task. I have searched online for a possible solution. I looked on StackOverflow site, but I still have not found any success to a solution for my issue. I am running into this issue

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

I am not sure why when I execute `gulp` in command line I get this error  `EADDRINUSE :::3000`. I have checked the port using `netstat -ano | findStr "9000"` the port isn't being called by another process. I am not sure why I run into this issue when I execute my gulp task. Can someone please provide some guidance? I will greatly appreciate I am running out of options.

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    var called = false;
    return nodemon({
      script: './server.js',
      ignore: [
        '../server/gulpfile',
        '../server/server.js',
        '../server/node_modules/'
      ],
    }).on('start', function () {
      if (!called) {
        cb();
        called = true;
      }
    }).on('restart', function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        reload({ stream: false });
      }, 1000);
      });
  });

  gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
   browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:9000',
    open: false,
    browser:'google-chrome',
    port: 9000, 
    notify: true
  });
});

// Static Server + watching scss/hbs files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

  browserSync.init({
      server: "./client"  
  });

  gulp.watch(['node_modules/**/*.scss', '../client/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("client/views/partials/*.hbs").on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
 gulp.task('default', ['js','serve', 'browser-sync']);
```

folder Structure 
[folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdckM.png)

Comment: Did you check 3000? You wrote you checked 9000 which isn't the address it says is in use.

Comment: I don't understand why its pointing to that address since my port specifies 9000. I am I doing something wrong with how I am setting up my nodemon and browserSync task?

Comment: I am also pointing to 9000  in  **server.js** file
    `app.listen(9000, () => {
      console.log('Running → PORT 9000');`

Answer (score 0):

earlier I had posted about an error I was running into using nodemon and browserSync together. I finally figured out the issue I was having. The reason I was getting **EARDINUSE3000** error was because I was calling browerSync twice within my **gulpfile.js** The solution to my issue was this.

```
gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    var called = false;
    return nodemon({
      script: './server.js',
      ignore: [
        '../server/gulpfile',
        '../server/server.js',
        '../server/node_modules/'
      ],
    }).on('start', function () {
      if (!called) {
        cb();
        called = true;
      }
    }).on('restart', function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        reload({ stream: false });
      }, 1000);
      });
  });


  gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
   browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000',
    open: false,
    browser:'google-chrome',
    port: 4000, 
    baseDir: 'build',
    notify: true,
  });

  gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', '../client/**/*.scss'],
  ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('client/**/*.hbs').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

 gulp.task('default', ['js', 'browser-sync']);
```

For anyone running into this issue in the future I hope this is helpful.